# how interfaces represent any type in Golang

Tags: go

It is said that `interface{}` represents any type in Go. For example, let us consider a `Marshal` function in `encoding/json` which is used to convert Go data structure into a JSON string. Its definition is

```
func Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error)
```

But we are passing a struct to it as a parameter like below.

```
type hello struct{
   Message string
}
data,err:= json.Marshal(hello{Message:'Hello world'})
```

How is Go handling this?

Comment: Like it is handling any interface combined with reflection. What is the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is runtime reflection.

From [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/):

> Package reflect implements run-time reflection, allowing a program to manipulate objects with arbitrary types. The typical use is to take a value with static type interface{} and extract its dynamic type information by calling TypeOf, which returns a Type.

Comment: Which begs the question: how does reflect figure out the type? This answer is missing the fact that interface values are tuples of a concrete type and a value of that type. See https://tour.golang.org/methods/11.